# TouchListener not detected when I quickly swipe my finger on Scroll. Android

Tags: android, swipe, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private float mInitialX;
        private float mInitialY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialX = event.getX();
                mInitialY = event.getY();
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
//                  int[] locations = new int[2];
//                      ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost)v.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().    getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(locations);
//                  int y1 = locations[1];
//                  if(y1 == actionBarHeight)
//                  {
//                  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
//                  }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                int[] locations2 = new int[2];
                    ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost)v.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().    getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(locations2);
                int y2 = locations2[1];
                if(y2 == actionBarHeight)
                {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                final float yDiff = y - mInitialY;
                if (yDiff > 0.0) {
//                        Log.d(tag, "SCROLL DOWN");
                    int[] locations0 = new int[2];
                        ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost)v.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(locations0);
                    int y1 = locations0[1];
                    if(((GridView)v).getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
                    {
                        ((GridView)v).smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }

                    break;

                } else if (yDiff < 0.0) {
//                        Log.d(tag, "SCROLL up");
                    int[] locations1 = new int[2];
                    ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost)v.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(locations1);
                    int y1 = locations1[1];
                    if(y1 == actionBarHeight)
                    {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                    break;

                }
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This code is working OK except for one thing. When I quickly swipe my finger down. This doesn't work as expected. But if I swap it down slowly it works and sometime it works even I do it quickly.

Actually there is a scroll Bar on my container as my container is bigger than my screen.

Comment: what is your goal actually?

Comment: My goal is to stop scroll up of grid view when parent scroll can scroll up. And stop scroll down of parent when grid view can scroll down. Hope you understand as It is little complicated. Check code for better understanding.

Comment: this is a bad design of having a scrollable child inside a scrollable parent, but see this:  http://androidmaterial.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling.html?m=1

Comment: I have done this, the problem is that child's on touch event is not detected when i swipe quickly with speed.

Comment: event is not detected? it cannot disappear just like that....override parent's dispatchTouchEvent and see what happens to it

Comment: What does it mean? I didn't understand.

Comment: touch events cannot disappear in the black hole,  try to locate where they are being dispatched

Comment: it is not dispatched, I'm sure about it. It only doesn't work when swapped quickly.

Comment: how can you be sure,  if you didn't override parents dispatchTouchEvent?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have missed that code inside action.down case. `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`  it was detecting